# How to check if an array contains an item from another array from within vue.js template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to show job.name if the job.name from jobs is also in anotherArray.

```
    <li v-for='job in jobs'>
    <template v-if="job.name in anotherArray"
      {{ job.name }}
    </template>
    </li>
```

note anotherArray is structured the same way as the jobs array.  So I want to be checking element.name in anotherArray

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed to get list of `anotherArrayName`, then create a method to check using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
computed: {
    anotherArrayName() {
        return this.anotherArray.map(item => item.name)
    }
},
methods: {
    isInclude(name) {
        return this.anotherArrayName.includes(name)
    }
}
```

and in template

```
 <li v-for='job in jobs'>
    <template v-if="isInclude(job.name)"
      {{ job.name }}
    </template>
</li>
```